# No route matches [GET] "/posts/assets/bootstrap.min.css"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am using rails 4.2.1 and although i have my images in assets/images folder the app does not render when i call it by CSS

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('assets/sendero-pumalin.jpg')">
```

So when i take a look at the server the error is this.. is looking into posts/assets/...

```
No route matches [GET] "/posts/assets/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Same thing with

```
No route matches [GET] "/posts/assets/clean-blog.min.js
```

Is a Routing error, does anyone knows why it is taking this path? By the way.. i am using scaffold for the posts and a bootstrap template

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change that to

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('../assets/sendero-pumalin.jpg')">
```

Comment: Just the fwd slash did the work..  (/assets/sendero-pumalin.jpg) Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it did work for you ,best of luck for your app ;)